# How to use a database connection class in my entire application

Tags: c#, winforms, class, connection-string

I have created a class for the MS Access database connection. It works fine on the majority of the forms within my Winforms app. However, I have a form where the user can add, edit or delete information from the database. I've constructed that part using a string, but when I remove the long database connection string I had there before and replace it with the class I created it throws an exception.

I've tried changing the code by removing the string, but I want to use the string method.

This is the code I have for the delete button click event

```
 string con = (@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =C:\Users\folder\Desktop\ApplicationFolder\AppName\bin\Debug\DataBase\DatabaseName.accdb");

      string Query = "delete from Employees2 where EmployeeName = '" + 
      this.txtAdminFEmployee.Text + "' ; ";
      OleDbConnection ConnectionString = new OleDbConnection(con);
      OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(Query, ConnectionString);
      OleDbDataReader reader;
      try
      {

        ConnectionString.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();



        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Employee Deleted Successfully", 
        "Information",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


        while (reader.Read())
        {

        }

      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        ConnectionString.Close();
```

This is the database class I created

```
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace AppName
{
  class OledbConnect
  {
    public OleDbConnection con;

    public void Connection()
    {
      con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseName.accdb");
    }
  }
}
```

I need to know how to use the database class in that string. I've tried different ways but nothing works. I am still new to c# and Google is not really returning anything I can use. Thanks

Comment: You are really reinventing the wheel here.  THere are much better/well developed libraries to talk to JET databases.  FOr example : https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/universal/docs/EnterpriseLib.html

Comment: Seeing sql-code and MessageBox code in the same code method............please read about layer separation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-web-application-architectures  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmeier/2008/09/06/layers-and-components/

Comment: There is also a great deal of functionality built into the NET provider you are ignoring.  A DataAdapter will "remember" your connection and open/close it as needed.  Gluing strings together to make SQL is dangerous (and many years out of date).  Use SQL Parameters always.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code works, but confusion is evident in the naming of variables.

```
string con = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =C:\Users\folder\Desktop\ApplicationFolder\AppName\bin\Debug\DataBase\DatabaseName.accdb";
```

(I've taken the un-needed parentheses off the declaration; it's just a string.)

Calling that string 'con' is a bit confusing. I'd call it 'connectionString', or maybe 'cs' for short.

```
  OleDbConnection ConnectionString = new OleDbConnection(con);
  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(Query, ConnectionString);
```

OK, so you correctly create an OleDbConnection, passing the connection string (con) to its constructor. This is good. But you confusingly call it ConnectionString. It isn't the connection string; it's the connection, and your code thereafter uses it correctly.

So that works. Confusing for a human to read because of the mis-naming of variables, but the compiler doesn't care what their names are - it knows very well that ConectionString is an OleDbConnection and doesn't feel any of the cognitive dissonance that I do when I look at it.

If you rename the variables in the original code as I've suggested, and then copy that code into your class (BTW, I'd just call it DbConnection; it's current name is very close to another class name which might also be confusing), paying attention to what each statement does and what each variable represents then you should be good to go.

Comment: Simon at rcl - I did everything you suggested and after all that the delete button click event is throwing an exception. it's saying that it can not connect to the database.

Comment: Do you know how to debug your program?